# Getting a bool or int result from a Stored Proc

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a SP that returns a bit.
This is how it's called from my `C#` program using `EF` context:

```
bool productCount = context.Database
                           .SqlQuery<bool>("EXEC [dbo].[SP_Name] @CatogeryID,@Id",
                            new SqlParameter("CatID", lngCatid),
                            new SqlParameter("SId", lngStudentId)
                           ).FirstOrDefault();
```

When the proc is run inside `SQL MMS` it gives correct result of True/False depending on the params.

The same proc always returns false when called.

What am I missing?

Any clues?

Comment: What's the SQL data type the stored proc returns?

Comment: In Old school (ADO), the return value was parameter 0. You might be returning something different with FirstOrDefault.

Comment: This is quite important: when you say "returns", do you mean the `return` statement? or do you mean the `select` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it's something in your stored proc not doing the select properly? Sample working code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testProc] 
    @inval bit output
AS
BEGIN
    declare @outval bit

    select @outval = @inval
    select @outval
END


using (var dbContext = new testContext())
{
    var data = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<bool>("exec testProc {0}",false).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Comment: Yup, that is the case. Thanks for your time.